# PHP: providing JSON for filling a datatable

Tags: php, json, datatables

Experienced in PHP, but new to jQuery: I want to fill a simple datatable with ajax getting the data from a json-encoded php-file.

**`table.php`: HTML snippet**

```
<head>...
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": 'deliver_tests.php',
            "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bPaginate": false
        });
    } );
</script>
</head>    
<body> ...
<div id="demo">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Abkürzung</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Patient</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**`deliver_tests.php`: code snippet:**

```
try {
    $sql = "SELECT tsID, tsStatus, tbShortname, tbName, paCode, tsCompleted_Date FROM test LEFT JOIN testbase ON tsTestBaseID = tbID LEFT JOIN patient ON tsPatientID = paID WHERE tsAccountID=:accID ORDER BY tsCompleted_Date DESC";
    $dbTests = $objDB->prepare($sql);
    $bind=array('accID' => $_SESSION['aID']);
    $dbTests->execute($bind);
    $tests = $dbTests->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $dbe) {
    // error 
}
$tests = array('aaData' => $tests);
echo json_encode($tests);
```

**See its output here**: http://pastebin.com/uZiLepSb

Calling `table.php`, I get a **js-alert:**

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): 
Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0
```

I guess I have to recompose that array?
I need a hint on how to continue from here - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each table row needs to be an array rather than an object in the JSON, you should be able to do this by using `PDO::FETCH_NUM` instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

See: [DataTables AJAX source example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html#latest_xhr)